# ASP.NET WebApi POST response URL or location

Tags: asp.net, url, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wanted the result URL/Location to be: api/orders/15
But the code below give me back api/orders?id=15

What should I change to make this happen?

```
[Route("api/orders", Name = "CreateOrder")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Order order)
{
   //...
   return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { newOrder.Id }, newOrder);
}
```

Here is routes defined under App_Start:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the attribute routing 
`[Route("api/orders", Name = "CreateOrder")]` is the culprit. It was there because another action (HttpGet) has it "by accident." That overrides the convention based routing which would give the correct URL in response location.

After I delete the attribute routing on both actions, the response location is the correct format based on the convention based routing. This solves this problem. However, it would be nice to know in the case that attribute based routing is required, what should be the syntax.